# How do I get a the time difference in seconds in sqlite?

Tags: sql, string, sqlite, datetime, date-arithmetic

I'm attempting to get the difference of time in seconds between two timestamps on an sqlite db (running sqlite 3.12.1) I've tried several things I have found here on stack overflow but nothing seems to be working as expected.

for reference I've tried creating the datetime field as both an integer and a text field and I get the same results. Below is the query I'm running and the results set that it produces.

essentially I'm attempting to replicate the datediff() function in SQL Server

```
 select cast(JulianDay('now') - JulianDay(last_upd_dt) * 24 * 60 * 60 As Integer) "gives me null value",
 last_upd_dt as "from date",
 datetime('now') as "To date this will be another field in the future",
 (datetime('now') - last_upd_dt  ) as "Gives me 2012 on all records"
 from sqlite_db
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date value should be stored as a `TEXT` datatype, in one of the formats supported by SQLite, such as `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS`.

Then, you can do

```
select (julianday('now') - julianday(last_upd_dt)) * 24 * 60 * 60 as date_diff_seconds
from mytable
```

Comment: When I use a datetime field formatted as text, I still get a null value.

Comment: @LukeHoffman: here is a db fiddle that demonstrates the concept: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fe25c54058ab07b33e03903e26c61e95. This works as explained, as you can see.

Comment: You're right, I created the a table from scratch and it worked, I wonder why it doesn't work with my actual dataset.... either way thanks for the help, I'll look elsewhere to see where the issues with my data are.

Comment: This assumes that there are 24 hours in every day and that there are 60 seconds in every minute, which are both falsehoods. It gives good approximation, but don't use it for anything mission-critical (like payout calculation etc).

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you should use parentheses around the difference of the dates and then multiply by 24 * 60 * 60.
But there is a much simpler way to get the difference between 2 dates in seconds:

```
select strftime('%s', 'now') - strftime('%s', last_upd_dt)
from sqlite_db
```

The function [`strftime()`](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) with the `'%s'` modifier returns the unix timestamp (the number of seconds since `'1970-01-01'`) of a date (provided it is formatted as `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`).